# Rearranging the page elements - JQuery

Tags: jquery, docking

I want to rearrange the elements in a page as i wish; for example visit http://www.pageflakes.com/.

How can i achieve that using JQuery? Is there any plugin? If not, how to start creating this? Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Is there a dock control available in JQuery UI? Or you mean to make use of drag and drop to achieve this?

Comment: Using the JQuery UI [Sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Sortable), you can do this by 'connecting' multiple 'columns'.

Comment: @NLV I mean "Here is your starting point, please go research yourself and come back to us if you have any problems down the line."

Comment: I've researched already and i'm using JQuery UI for my application to move things around. But i want to avoid the controls being overlapped while dragging. So i've done my home work already and i'm stuck at this point.

Comment: @sje - Using sortable() is a good idea. But i'm not able to drag the controls outside the 'sortable' parent.  But i want to, actually. I just want to avoid overlapping while dragging a control over another control. But i dont want to restrict that. I want to dock that and move them automatically.

Comment: have a look at: http://interface.eyecon.ro/  specifically: http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/sort.html